# inline edit in jqgrid not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have my jQuery code like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

         var lastsel;

    $('#jqgProducts').jqGrid({
             //url from wich data should be requested
             url: '@Url.Action("CompOff")',
         //type of data
         datatype: 'json',
         //url access method type

         mtype: 'POST',
         //columns names

         ondblClickRow: function (id) {
             if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                 jQuery('#list').restoreRow(lastsel);
                 jQuery('#list').editRow(id, true);
                 lastsel = id;
             }
             $('#jqgProducts').editRow(id, true,null, null);
         },

         editurl: '@Url.Action("CompOffEdit")',
         colNames: ['IdNr', 'CompOffDate', 'Description', 'ExpiryDate', 'IsApproved', 'AppliedOn'],
         //columns model
         colModel: [
                    { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', align: 'center', editable: true, hidden: true},
                        { name: 'CompOffDate', index: 'CompOffDate', align: 'center', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/Y' }, editable: true },
                          { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', align: 'center', editable: true, editoptions: { maxlength: 200} },
                        { name: 'ExpiryDate', index: 'ExpiryDate', align: 'center', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/Y' }, editable: false },
                        { name: 'IsApproved', index: 'IsApproved', align: 'center', editable: false },

                        { name: 'AppliedOn', index: 'AppliedOn', align: 'center', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/Y' }, editable: false }

                      ],
         //pager for grid
         pager: $('#jqgpProducts'),
         //number of rows per page
         rowNum: 10,
         //initial sorting column
         sortname: 'CompOffDate',
         //initial sorting direction
         sortorder: 'asc',
         //we want to display total records count
         viewrecords: true,

         caption: 'Comp Off Details',
         //grid height
         height: '100%',

         jsonReader: {
             root: "rows",
             page: "page",
             total: "total",
             records: "records",
             repeatitems: false,
             cell: "cell",
             id: "id",
             userdata: "userdata"
         }
     });
```

});

my controller like this

```
   public ActionResult CompOffEdit(int Id,DateTime CompOffDate, string Description)
    {
        RegisterCompOff r = db.RegisterCompOffs.Where(l=>l.Id==Id).SingleOrDefault();
        if (!(r == null))
        {
            r.CompOffDate = CompOffDate;
            r.Description = Description;
            db.Entry(r).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Content("true");
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("false");
        }

    }
```

when i'm trying to save the edits to db..i get this exception

`The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'idnr' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult CompOffEdit(Int32, System.DateTime, System.String)' in 'AGS.Hrms.Controllers.CompOffController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters`

user can only edit compoff date and description here...and my id field which i'm picking from database is hidden.

can someone help me to rectify this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename `idnr` parameter of the `CompOffEdit` action to `id` or you should rename the default `id` name of the parameter sending to the server during the row editing to `idnr`. You can use `prmNames: {id: "idnr"}` option of jqGrid for this.

In the same way you should rename `compOff` parameter of `CompOffEdit` action to `CompOffDate` and `reason` to `Description`. Alternatively you can use some class instance, which has `CompOffDate` and `Description` as properties, as the parameter of `CompOffEdit` action. In the case the `CompOffDate` and `Description` properties will be initialized with the values from the editing row.

Comment: whatever you said plus i had to send this id parameter from my data base as a hidden field to view and make it as editable, so when user goes for inline editing this value goes and sit in Id field of my compoffedit method. i have updated my code.